# Fourier uniqueness theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I am reading Theorem 26.2 in the book "Probability and Measure" (2nd ed.) by Patrick Billingsley. In the proof of that theorem, the author claims that:

**Fact** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be probability measures on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and set
$$A=\left\{\;\left(a,b\right]\;\middle|\;\mu(\{a\})=\mu(\{b\})=\nu(\{a\})=\nu(\{b\})=0\right\}.$$
Then $\sigma(A)$ coincides with the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have been thinking about this result, but have absolutely no clues on this. It does not seem straightforward. So my question is:

**Question** What is a clean way to prove this?

Any hint/help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\mu \{x\}=\nu \{x\}=0$ for all but countable number of $x$. So there is a countable set $\{t_1,t_2,...\}$ such that the given class contains all intervals $(a,b]$ whose end points are not in this countable set. Can you express any interval in terms of these using countable unions /intersections? (The complement of any countable set is dense). Will be glad to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Would you mind explaning why $\mu\{x\}=\nu\{x\}$ for all but countable number of $x$?

Comment: @weirdo There can only be $n$ points $x$ such that $\mu \{x\} >\frac 1 n$ because $\mu$ is a probability measure. Take union of these finite sets to get a countable set $S$ such that  $\mu \{x\}=0$ whenever $x \notin S$.

Comment: I just want to make sure I did this correctly. So the end points of intervals in $A$ belong to a dense set. Thus, given $\alpha<\beta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exist $\alpha_{n} \downarrow \alpha$ (the sequence belongs to the dense set) and $\beta_{n}\uparrow \beta$ and $\alpha_n\neq\alpha$, $\beta_n\neq\beta$. So we have $(\alpha,\beta)=\cup (\alpha_{n},\beta_{n})$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @weirdo You are right.